# How to add different shipping price for additional item

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

In WooCommerce I am trying to have different shipping prices based on cart item count.

Example:

- 1 item $5
- 2 item $5 + $2
- 3 item $5 + (2 x 2$) … *and so on* …

So the first item will set a cost of $5 and all additional items will add 2$ for each of them.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** - Two steps:

1) Add this code that will make your shipping calculation cost based on cart items count *(the total quantity of items)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'progressive_flat_rate_cost_calculation', 10, 2 );
function progressive_flat_rate_cost_calculation( $rates, $package )
{
    // The cart count (total items in cart)
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $taxes = array();

    $cost = 5; // Cost for the 1st item
    $other = 2; // Cost for additional items

    // Calculation
    if( $cart_count > 1 )
        $cost += ($cart_count - 1) * $other;

    // Iterating through each shipping rate
    foreach($rates as $rate_key => $rate_values){
        $method_id = $rate_values->method_id;
        $rate_id = $rate_values->id;
        // Targeting "Flat Rate" shipping method
        if ( 'flat_rate' === $method_id ) {
            // Set the new calculated rate cost
            $rates[$rate_id]->cost = number_format($rates[$rate_id]->cost * $cost, 2);
            // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            foreach ($rates[$rate_id]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$key] > 0 ){ // set the new tax cost
                    $taxes[$key] = number_format( $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$key] * $cost, 2 );
                    $has_taxes = true;
                } else {
                    $has_taxes = false;
                }
            }
            if( $has_taxes )
                $rates[$rate_id]->taxes = $taxes;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

2) Now, In the general shipping settings, you will need to set a **"Flat rate"** shipping method for each Shipping Zones which cost will be set to **`1`** (in your WooCommerce shipping settings).

> **Sometimes you will need to refresh shipping zones caches (in woocommerce shipping settings for each zone):**
>  Disabling each Flat rate, then save, then enabling back this flat rate and save.
>   Is better to start on a fresh new cart *(so empty it before testing)*

This code is tested on WooCommerce 3+ and works

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by setting a Flat rate only... No code is required.

Just activate flat rate shipping...

In cost write this rule ---

5 + 2 * ( [qty] - 1 )